# How do I stop matplotlib from rearranging my bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a bar chart from pd.DataFrame. Unfortunately, matplotlib keeps arranging my bars around, showing N=100, N=150,N=50 instead of 50,100,150

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"N": ["N=50","N=100","N=150","N=50","N=100","N=150","N=50","N=100","N=150"],\
                   "clm2": profit[0:len(profit)],\
                   "User": ["2x2x2","2x2x2","2x2x2","3x3x3","3x3x3","3x3x3","4x4x4","4x4x4","4x4x4"]})



with PdfPages('profit.pdf') as pdf:
    ax1= df1.pivot(index = "User", columns = "N", values = "clm2")
    plt.x_range = FactorRange(factors=df1["N"].tolist())
    ax1.plot.bar(figsize=(7,7),edgecolor = "white",rot=0).set_ylabel("Profits")

    pdf.savefig()
```

Comment: What you call `ax1` is a pandas dataframe. If you investigate its index, you see in the order you get in the plot. You may change the index if you want.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hi, how do I check the index and reorder it?